# Get-Childitem using lots of memory

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

i know there are lots of threads already to this topic and i tried to put all the ideas into my powershell code as well to make get-childitem less memory hungry but still it eats up a lot of memory.

Here is my thing: Having a directory with more than 10 Mio sub directories that i need to go through using get-childitem. Memory consumption goes up to more than 50GB and at some point i got to kill the process not killing my server.

Here is my code. It recursively searches for some xml files (each sub directory has one) and if it found that xml file, read the content and add some values to two variables ($a and $b). I need the try-catch because sometimes the xml files are corrupt and don't have the desired information.

```
$a = $b = 0
gci -Recurse -File -Filter "file.xml" -path C:\dir\ | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        $FullName = $_.FullName
        [xml]$content = gc $_.FullName
        $a += ($content.Directory.File | % {$_.Size} | measure-object -sum).sum
        $b += $content.Directory.File.count
    } catch {
        (Get-date -Format "MMM dd HH:mm:ss") + " Error: Problem executing " + $FullName + ". Error message: " + $_.Exception.Message | Out-File $LogFile -Append    
    }
}
```

Anyone got an idea to make it run with less memory usage?

Thx

Edit:
This is an example xml file that it searches for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Directory>
    <File Name="xxxxxx.doc">
        <Size>22222</Size>
        <CreationTime>xxxxxxxxx</CreationTime>
    </File>
    <File Name="yyyyy.doc">
        <Size>11111</Size>
        <CreationTime>20140723141441</CreationTime>
    </File>
</Directory>
```

Comment: `$array += ...` <-- this will cause PowerShell to allocate a new array and copy the existing array items to the new array - these repeated array-copy ops will keep adding memory pressure as the arrays grow in size. Perhaps you'll want to write your information to disk instead? What's the next step for `$a` and `$b` anyway? What should happen after the loop finishes?

Comment: $a and $b are both integer values and will put into a csv file after finishing the loop.

Comment: is this all the code? please include everything

Comment: In that case I'd suggest using `XPathDocument`/`XPathNavigator` instead. I'll try to write up an example later if @SantiagoSquarzon doesn't beat me to it ;-)

Comment: @marcuse Can you share a sample document, or link to the schema documentation, by any chance?

Comment: += kills puppies.

Comment: There is nothing more to show. This is the main part of the code. Only some echos before and after and after the get-childitem the two variables $a and $b are outputted into a text file

Comment: Added an example xml file to the original post

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a definitive answer but I believe with a these changes the memory consumption should be lower and the code should also run faster. The problems I see with your current code:

1. The use of `Get-Content` to read the file and load the Xml. `Get-Content` is not only slow but it also add additional data in the form of ETS properties to each string it processes, making reading content with it very slow. Changed this to use [`XmlDocument.Load` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.load?view=net-7.0).
2. The use of `ForEach-Object`, main issue here is that everything that its scriptblock is dot sourced, everything defined inside it becomes part of the user's session. Changed this to use an anonymous function. It will be faster and more efficient for sure.
3. This really depends how many times you're hitting the `catch` block, in other words, how many Xml files are corrupted but I think its worth changing `Out-File -Append` to a [`SteppablePipeline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.getsteppablepipeline?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) using `Set-Content` inside it, this way we keep the file stream open until all processing is done. With `Out-File -Append` you would be opening the file stream, seeking the end of the stream, writing the new content and closing the file stream each time there is an error.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter 'file.xml' -Path C:\dir | & {
    begin {
        $xml = [xml]::new()
        $size = $count = 0
        $msg = '{0} Error: Problem executing {1}. Error message: {2}.'
        # change the path to the log file here
        $logfile = { Set-Content 'path\to\logfile.log' }.GetSteppablePipeline()
        $logfile.Begin($true)
    }
    process {
        try {
            $FullName = $_.FullName
            $xml.Load($FullName)
            foreach ($node in $xml.Directory.File) {
                $size += $node.Size
                $count++
            }
        }
        catch {
            $logfile.Process($msg -f @(
                (Get-Date -Format 'MMM dd HH:mm:ss')
                $FullName
                $_.Exception.Message
            ))
        }
    }
    end {
        $logfile.End()

        [pscustomobject]@{
            TotalSize  = $size
            TotalCount = $count
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though I don't recommend doing manual garbage collection: calling the garbage collector every x iterations might also free up a lot of memory.

Comment: I agree @bluuf but I'm expecting OP's feedback to see if it is needed or not

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks for your effort. 
I gotta try replacing `Get-Content` with the xmlload function and see how it goes.
Last time i ran the script, the catch block was not even reached once. 
Regarding `Foreach-object` i am not really sure, but i gotta try it your way as well. 
Gonna run it starting next week, as i dont have access to the system over the weekend and i wannt monitor it

Also what i might have missed to tell in my original post: The script is started via Windows Task Scheduler automatically using the `SYSTEM` user. Dont know if this makes any differences.

Comment: Ok, i now replaced `Get-Content`  with XML.Load function and also used `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` instead of Get-Childitem and ran it in some test environement (This has way less files and folders) and it took 8min instead of 15min with my original code. Don't know if memory consuption improved as well. I gotta test that with prod environement next week.

Comment: @marcuse note that you need `.EnumerateFiles('*', [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories)` if you want to perform a recursive lookup, its not recursive by default. Also note that this will find hidden and system files by default (different than `Get-ChildItem` which needs `-Force`) also __if there is any error the enumeration will stop__ meaning, there will be files without processing

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon
Yes, i added the `AllDirectories` option for recurse lookup

Answer (score -2):

Try following.  I updated to include all directories.
:

```
 $a = $b = 0
 foreach($file in [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles('c:\dir', 'file.xml', [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories)){
    try {
        $FullName = $file
        $content = gc $file
        $a += ($content.Directory.File | % {$file.Size} | measure-object -sum).sum
        $b += $content.Directory.File.count
    } catch {
        (Get-date -Format "MMM dd HH:mm:ss") + " Error: Problem executing " + $FullName + ". Error message: " + $file.Exception.Message | Out-File $LogFile -Append    
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because 1) `Directory.GetFiles()` is a blocking call, first `foreach` iteration won't start until all files have been discovered, 2) it doesn't recurse by default, and 3) it seems unlikely that the file discovery step is the real memory sink here

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen : The memory error is caused because original code is not blocking.  The original code is getting every file and keeping name in memory.  My code does not keep all the names in memory.  What is wrong with running without blocking?  I thought the default it does recurse.

Comment: "My code does not keep all the names in memory" - it really does - `Directory.GetFiles()` returns a fixed-size array. You can't know the size before having enumerated all the files, so we can infer it must be a blocking call :) Perhaps you're getting `Direcory.GetFiles()` confused with `Directory.EnumerateFiles()`? The latter returns an enumerator, so the loop can start immediately

Comment: It is wrong to mark the answer with negative points when it solves the issue.

Comment: We don't know that it solves the issue, we don't have a copy of OPs input data :)

Comment: I agree 100% with Mathias and I also downvoted for the same reasons he did in addition to answering with "Try following." not being an informative answer. If you are gonna answer with "Try following." mind as well just paste your code there and don't add anything